# Is there a "switch to buffer" hook?

Tags: buffers, hooks, advice

I'm running emacs 26.3. I want to run a hook every time I switch to a buffer. However, I have not been able to find any kind of "buffer switch hook".

If I want to always run a function when switching to a buffer, do I have to do something like wrapping `switch-to-buffer` with advice? Or is there some other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Emacs 27.1 or later, you can use:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `window-selection-change-functions`

Use `add-hook` with the `LOCAL` argument set a function for a specific buffer.

For more details see <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Window Hooks`

Comment: Thank you! I'm on 26.3, as I mentioned ... but I guess it's time for me to upgrade. :)

Comment: I managed to miss that, sorry.  FWIW you can see the relevant part of the manual online at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Hooks.html (which still doesn't help unless you upgrade, but in case you wanted to check those docs first).

Comment: In 26.3, you could take a look at `C-h v buffer-list-update-hook` and see if you can carefully bend that to your purposes.

Comment: Well, I managed to upgrade fairly painlessly to 27.2, so all is well. Thank you again!

Comment: If by "switch to a buffer" you *only* mean cases when the buffer gets displayed in a window in which it was not *already* displayed (i.e. a window configuration is going to change in some frame), then you can use a buffer-local `window-configuration-change-hook` in 26.3.

Comment: Oh, excellent :)